# Unable to get format data cell using ClosedXML

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, closedxml

I'm having problems getting Excel to format cells using closedxml.

My Excel cell is formatted as short date however when I check datatype it gives me string instead of date (or datetime).

I have tried to get format type in this way:

```
foreach (var item in wRange.Rows())
{
    var array = new object[wCol];
    for (int y = 1; y <= wCol; y++)
    {
        try
        {
            var t = item.Cell(y).Value;
```

and `item.Cell(y)` gives me string instead of datetime.

Why is my cell not DateTime type? 
How do I get it to format as short date?

Answer (score 2):

Use `GetDateTime()` or `GetValue<T>()` function:

```
var t = item.Cell(y).GetDateTime();
```

or

```
var t = item.Cell(y).GetValue<DateTime>();
```

Comment: the problem is not to have datetime value but format cell is wrong. item.Cell(y).DataType is string and not datetime as soon as cell is formatted as date